# Travis: xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, travis-ci, xcodebuild

I'm trying to implement continuous integration using travis-ci.org.

Here is my current .travis.yml config:

```
language: swift
osx_image: xcode8.3.3
xcode_project: AutomatediOSBuild.xcodeproj #3
xcode_scheme: Debug
#xcode_sdk: iphonesimulator10.0
script:
  - xcodebuild -scheme AutomatediOSBuild -project AutomatediOSBuild.xcodeproj -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6s,OS=10.3.1' build test
```

But I'm getting the following error on travis:

```
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
        { platform:iOS Simulator, OS:10.3.1, name:iPhone 6s }
    The requested device could not be found because no available devices matched the request.
The command "xcodebuild -scheme myProject -project myProject.xcodeproj -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6s,OS=10.3.1' build test" exited with 70.
```

If I run in the command line:

```
xcodebuild -scheme myProject -project myProject.xcodeproj -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6s,OS=10.3.1' build test
```

I have no errors. Any of you knows why I'm getting this errors? or if there is any work around this error?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you checked with `xcrun instruments -w "iPhone 6s"` or with `xcrun instruments -w "*"` to see what devices/simulators are available and if yours is one of them? Could it be that you have a mismatch with the OS version?

Comment: did you figure out what the problem was? I'm seeing the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Travis environment for xcodebuild is likely different from yours, namely you have locally the correct Simulator corresponding to your `-destination` option, but your Travis-ci container does not.

The Job logs should give you a bit more info, like :

```
The requested device could not be found because no available devices matched the request.
585
586 Available destinations for the "stackoverflow" scheme:
587     { platform:iOS Simulator, id:5B...65, OS:13.2.2, name:iPad (7th generation) }
588     { platform:iOS Simulator, id:1A...DA, OS:13.2.2, name:iPhone 8 }
```

Travis lists the available simulators for the selected `osx_image` on the [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/osx/#xcode-83), and this [mokacoding post](https://www.mokacoding.com/blog/xcodebuild-destination-options/) gives good explanations.

I also found out that you must give the exact OS version, e.g. in my example above:

```
xcode_destination: platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=13.2  # fails
xcode_destination: platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=13.2.2  # works
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a target I created with Xcode 9.4 and was trying to run on travis with Xcode 9.3.  The tvOS deployment target in Build Settings was 11.4. I changed it back to 11.1 and travis started working:

```
--- a/GoogleUtilities/Example/GoogleUtilities.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
+++ b/GoogleUtilities/Example/GoogleUtilities.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
@@ -974,7 +974,7 @@
                                PRODUCT_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME)";
                                SDKROOT = appletvos;
                                TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 3;
-                               TVOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.4;
+                               TVOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.1;
                        };
```

Answer (score 0):

**React Native Docs:**

https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-simulator-ios

**1. View Devices:**

```
xcrun simctl list devices
```

**2. Look for the id for your device (The issue is that it doesn't match):**

```
6FC6D243-9AD0-4CA5-BCD0-3AE32D536A27
```

**3. Run iOS Simulator with new ID**

```
npx react-native run-ios --udid=6FC6D243-9AD0-4CA5-BCD0-3AE32D536A27
```